# Can LTSPICE compile BSIM4 models

Tags: ltspice, model, ngspice

While NGSPICE can compile and run BSIM4 models, I could mot find anywhere reference to LTSPICE being able to run these models. Has anyone tried, and saw that it worked, or knows that this will probably/definitely not work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to LTspice's own help document ([link to an outdated cached version](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/M_MOSFET.htm); also pasted below), a LEVEL=14 MOSFET model is BSIM4.6.1.  According to the [ngspice manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs.html) (Table 11.1; snipped below), it also uses 14 but can also use 54 as an alias.  If you are having trouble running a specific model in LTspice, change the `LEVEL=54` in the model description to `LEVEL=14`.

```
There are seven monolithic MOSFET device models. The model parameter LEVEL specifies the model to be used. The default level is one.

level   model

------------------------------------------------------

 1   Shichman-Hodges

 2   MOS2(see A. Vladimirescu and S. Liu, The Simulation of MOS Integrated Circuits Using SPICE2, ERL Memo No. M80/7, Electronics Research Laboratory University of California, Berkeley, October 1980)

 3   MOS3, a semi-empirical model(see reference for level 2)

 4   BSIM (see B. J. Sheu, D. L. Scharfetter, and P. K. Ko, SPICE2 Implementation of BSIM. ERL Memo No. ERL M85/42, Electronics Research Laboratory University of California, Berkeley, May 1985)

 5   BSIM2 (see Min-Chie Jeng, Design and Modeling of Deep-Submicrometer MOSFETs ERL Memo Nos. ERL M90/90, Electronics Research Laboratory University of California, Berkeley, October 1990)

 6   MOS6 (see T. Sakurai and A. R. Newton, A Simple MOSFET Model for Circuit Analysis and its application to CMOS gate delay analysis and series-connected MOSFET Structure, ERL Memo No. ERL M90/19, Electronics Research Laboratory, University of California, Berkeley, March 1990)

 8   BSIM3v3.3.0 from University of California, Berkeley as of July 29, 2005

 9   BSIMSOI3.2 (Silicon on insulator) from the BSIM Research Group of the University of California, Berkeley, February 2004.

12   EKV 2.6 based on code from Ecole Polytechnique Federale de Lausanne. See http://legwww.epfl.ch/ekv and "The EPFL-EKV MOSFET Model Equations for Simulation, Version 2.6", M. Bucher, C. Lallement, F. Theodoloz, C. Enz, F. Krummenacher, EPFL-DE-LEG, June 1997.

14   BSIM4.6.1 from the University of California, Berkeley BSIM Research Group, May 18, 2007.

73   HiSIMHV version 1.2 from the Hiroshima University and STARC
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers. I never knew these cached things.

Comment: @user1134991 You should just press F1 to open the built-in help.  If you are on Linux, you might need to manually open up `LTspiceHelp.chm` in the install folder.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, LTspice does not offer a feature to extract BSIM4 modelcards from technology data -- if it is what you call "to compile BSIM4 model". But you may find a model you need on [the Predictive Technology Model (PTM) website](http://ptm.asu.edu/)'s webpage http://ptm.asu.edu/latest.html or generate your own model with [their online CMOS generator](http://ptm.asu.edu/cgi-bin/test/nanocmos.cgi).

You can use the downloaded models with LTspice. In the example, I use NMOS/PMOS modelcards from the file http://bsim.berkeley.edu/BSIM4/BSIM461.zip of [BSIM models' repository](http://bsim.berkeley.edu/models/bsim4/), the section Previous Versions, files "BSIM461/test/modelcard.nmos", "BSIM461/test/modelcard.pmos".

An LTspice schematic drawing of a diffpair circuit with active load:

[image]

The simulation plot:

[image]

You can also use predefined BSIM4 models with LTspice, setting LEVEL=14 for the device model in the components nmos4, pmos4. See LTspice's help and manuals.

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately, I have just read that I can't use the software at all, due to a legal issue... Had I known, I would not have troubled y'áll.